# Multi class AUC ROC score in python

Tags: python, multiclass-classification, auc

I would like to calculate AUC ROC score for three classes 0, 1, 2. After I get the prediction probability using `predict_proda`, I use `roc_auc_score(y_test_over, y_prob, multi_class="ovo", average="macro")`. However, I get the error [image]

Then, I use the code from https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3298 that

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

def multiclass_roc_auc_score(truth, pred, average="macro"):

   lb = LabelBinarizer()
   lb.fit(truth)

   truth = lb.transform(truth)
   pred = lb.transform(pred)

   return roc_auc_score(truth, pred, average=average)
```

But I still get an error when I call this function, which says [image]

Can anyone help me solve this? Thank you!

Comment: The predictions are already binarized I think.

Comment: @Sy Ker Thank you for replying! I rerun the function without transforming the predictions but get another error saying "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [198, 4284]". May I ask how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

For the ROC curve, you need a classifier with a decision function. [Example from the documentation;](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html)

```
# caculate ROC for all class 

y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)

# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
```

Than plot what you have found, you will have to repeat for each class;

```
# plot of a ROC curve for a specific class

plt.figure()
lw = 2
plt.plot(fpr[2], tpr[2], color='darkorange',
         lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc[2])
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```